# C Assign a string value to a string element in a struct using a function

Tags: c, string, function, struct, char

I need to assign a string (char of size [255]) to an element in a struct. The struct looks like this:

```
struct node{
   int ID, YEAR, MONTH, DAY
   char CATEGORY[255], DETAIL[255];
   double AMOUNT;
   struct node * next;
}
 struct node * head = NULL;
```

and I have code that gets values from a text file and sets it as a variable that I then pass to the add_struct function which looks like this:

```
void add_struct(int i, char c, char d, double a, int y, int m, int da){
   if (head == NULL){
        head = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->ID = i;
        head->CATEGORY = c;
        head->DETAIL = d;
        head->AMOUNT = a;
        head->YEAR = y;
        head->MONTH = m;
        head->DAY = da;
  }

  else {
        struct node * p = head;
        while(p->next != NULL) p = p->next;
        p->next = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        p->next->ID = i;
        p->next->CATEGORY = c;
        p->next->DETAIL = d;
        p->next->AMOUNT = a;
        p->next->YEAR = y;
        p->next->MONTH = m;
        p->next->DAY = da;
   }
}
```

I get error message:

```
"incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[255]' from type 'char'"
```

How do I assign these values to elements CATEGORY and DETAIL properly?

Comment: `char c` --> `char *c`... `p->next->CATEGORY = c;`--> `strcpy(p->next->CATEGORY, c);`

Comment: Does `char c, char d,` really meant a single char or a pointer to char(string)?

Comment: Also Need XXX`->next = NULL;`

Comment: Also don't cast `malloc`'s return value, just do `head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you this fixed it right up

Comment: I am now getting segmentation fault (core dumped) error when running it and it seems to be caused by the strcpy lines

Answer (score 1):

The `CATEGORY` and `DETAIL` field of the struct are defined as arrays of 255 chars, while `c` and `d` are variables of `char`. So you should change the function to `void add_struct(int i, char *c, char *d, double a, int y, int m, int da)`, and copy the string to the allocated struct:

```
strcpy(head->CATEGORY, c);
strcpy(head->DETAIL, d);
```

Comment: the values c and d are not just characters though but char arrays of size 255 as well. an example would be like the CATEGORY being "Restaurant" and the DETAIL being "Waffle House". Does this still work?

Comment: @user276019 in that case, you need to fix the function signature, and use `strcpy` in the function. see my post.